# Editing inlineformsets associated with parent form

Tags: python, django, inline-formset

I have created an invoice and items in it using Modelform and inlineforset_factory.
Now I am trying to create edit form, but I am getting MultiValueDictKeyError when I try to edit those inline fields. If I just create new inlineformsets I can edit Modelform just fine. After one hour of googling I am no closer to finding any solution.

```
maxItems = 20
ItemFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Invoice, Item, can_delete=True, extra=maxItems)
```

Creating of new invoice (working perfectly)

```
def new_invoice(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = InvoiceForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        invoice = form.save(commit=False)
        item_formset = ItemFormSet(request.POST,instance=invoice)
        if item_formset.is_valid():
            invoice.dateCreated = datetime.datetime.now()
            invoice.save()
            item_formset.save()
            return redirect('list/new0')
else:
    form = InvoiceForm()
    item_formset = ItemFormSet(instance=Invoice())
return render(request, "form.html", {"form": form, "item_formset": item_formset })
```

Editing invoice (MultiValueDictKeyError)

```
def edit_invoice(request, invoice_id):
invoicer = get_object_or_404(Invoice, pk=invoice_id)
if request.method == "POST":
    form = InvoiceForm(request.POST, instance=invoicer)
    if form.is_valid():
        invoice = form.save(commit=False)
        item_formset = ItemFormSet(request.POST,instance=invoice)
        if item_formset.is_valid():
            invoice.dateCreated = datetime.datetime.now()
            invoice.save()
            item_formset.save()
            return redirect('list/new0')
else:
    form = InvoiceForm(instance=invoicer)
    item_formset = ItemFormSet(instance=invoicer)
return render(request, "form.html", {"form": form, "item_formset": item_formset })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've found that problem was not in the views.py nor in forms.py, but in template. Because I've built the template without using      {{form.as_p/table/...}}       The form had some extra inputs - DELETE,ID and foreignKey... after adding them to my for loop, everything works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two variables, `invoicer` and `invoice` that I assume are different instances of the same object.  Try re-writing your edit view like this:

```
def edit_invoice(request, invoice_id):
    invoice = get_object_or_404(Invoice, pk=invoice_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InvoiceForm(request.POST, instance=invoice)
        formset = ItemFormSet(request.POST, instance=invoice)
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            invoice = form.save()
            invoice.dateCreated = datetime.datetime.now()
            invoice.save()
            formset.save()
            return redirect('list/new0')
    else:
        form = InvoiceForm(instance=invoice)
        formset = ItemFormSet(instance=invoice)
    context = {
      'form': form,
      'formset': formset,
    }
    return render(request, 'form.html', context)
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Sadly, it does exactly what happend to me when I try to submit it. MultiValueDictKeyError with "u'item_set-0-id'".. I suspect that for some reason they are not being edited but replaced. I am trying another way... delete all items in selected invoice and add them anew... I am new to stackoverflow, I pressume I should let you know by adding a comment, hope its the correct way. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  Sorry it didn't work for you :-/